# Follow changed a href

Tags: jquery

I have a href:

```
<a href="#" id="my_href">here we go</a>
```

And my jQuery is:

```
$('#my_href').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //$(this).attr('http://www.google.com').click(); // <== I tried also this
  $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com').trigger('click');
});
```

All I want is when user clicks on href, the href must change the `href` attribute and follow that link.

The above code (both examples) is not working. Please, where I am doing mistake?

Comment: Why not `location.href = 'google.com';`

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what is it that you are trying to do...

Comment: facepalm... yes, location.href will work. Sorry for the question...

Comment: use location.href = 'http://google.com';

Comment: Its normal question, so why there are again stupid downvoters???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
$('#my_href').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
});
```

Comment: I do not think href is a method.

Answer (score 3):

You are causing an infinite loop because triggering click() is causing it to keep calling the function. You either need to unbind the click or do not cancel the click method.

```
$('#my_href').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this)
        .attr('href', '//www.example.com')
        .off("click")
        .get(0).click();
});
```

or just

```
$('#my_href').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).attr('href', '//www.example.com');
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you use `.get(0)`

Comment: Because jQuery's `.click()` or `.trigger("click")` does not actually click the element so I call click on the DOM and it will fire the event.

Comment: Thank you. This is also the solution.

Answer (score -2):

use this code

```
$('#my_href').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).attr('href','http://www.google.com').click();
});
```

Comment: yes @TamilSelvan, just correct question code, but should handle loop problem!

Comment: Do you think there is a difference between `.click()` and `.trigger("click")`? Read the documentation https://api.jquery.com/click/#click *"**This method is a shortcut for** .on( "click", handler ) in the first two variations, and **.trigger( "click" )** in the third."*